# How do I install elementaryOS 0.4 Loki on Virtualbox?

Tags: release-loki, virtualization

I'm trying to get elementaryOS working on Virtualbox to test it out, so i took it from the OSArchive website, but now i'm confused because i get the "iso" on winrar, but there is no iso file! And there's also all these files and documents, so can someone tell me, what or where is the iso file? (Note: I tried to put in the efi.img file with floppy controller but it didn't work so i'm even more confused...)

Comment: If you just want to test it out you better create a live cd on a usb stick and boot the computer from it to just see how it goes. I think rufus is a good tool for this in windows. But Loki will be out of support soon, so I recommend you to try the latest Juno release from the elementary os official website.

Answer (score 1):

The iso file you downloaded is NOT supposed to be opened with WinRar. To achieve what you want, you have to open VirtualBox, create a new Linux machine and, at the first startup, point it towards the iso file you downloaded. Take a look at the gif below for a quick tutorial ([better quality here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffftf.jpg)). When creating the virtual machine, I suggest allocating at least 2GB of RAM if possible.

After installing elementary OS inside your new virtual machine, you should also install VirtualBox guest additions (better mouse integration, improved video support...) [This tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/virtualbox-guest-additions-ubuntu/) is for Ubuntu, but it will work just the same for any Debian based Linux distribution.

[Here](https://blog.storagecraft.com/the-dead-simple-guide-to-installing-a-linux-virtual-machine-on-windows/) you can find a detailed step-by-step tutorial on setting-up a new Linux machine.

As a side note, elementary OS performs a bit unsatisfactory in VirtualBox, so the experience is not really as good as running it on real hardware.

[image: a poor quality gif with the steps]

Comment: Ok, but where can i find the iso file? It gave me the things in WinRAR but i cannot find an iso image...

Comment: Well, clicking this link (http://dl.sda1.eu/linux/elementary/elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20180214.iso) will download elementary OS Loki 0.4.1 from OSArchive. If you need a different version, use this link ( https://osarchive.sda1.eu/elementary-os) and choose a different one. The iso file you download might have a WinRAR icon in Windows, but do not open in WinRAR. Use the instructions above to open it in VirtualBox.